# How to extend a XAML control with new properties properly?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a new philosophic question, which aims at underline differences between old WPF patterns and the new UWP ones.

I would like to extend a standard control (e.g. a Button) with new properties, in UWP environment, not WPF.

In WPF, I noticed that it was possible to create a Custom Control with two files: a Themes/Generics.xaml and a MyCustomControl.cs.

In UWP, it creates only the .cs file... does it mean that if I want to modify even the XAML content of a Button (let's say that I would like to create an IconButton: A Button whose content is a SymbolIcon and a Textblock), it would be impossible?

I know that I could use a "User Control", but it is a generic control and I would loose all the properties of the control that I want to customize (e.g. in my case, the Click event, etc.)... I could even extend a User Control to include all the properties of the wanted control... but it would take too long.

**To the point: what is the best and proper way to customize and extend a standard XAML control  by code AND Xaml, in UWP environment?**

As an example, think at a classic task: creating an IconButton, as I said above... a Button with it's Content beeing a Grid with a SymbolIcon and a Textblock as children.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you want a button with a symbol and text on it ?

Comment: That was only an example.  I woul dlike to be able to extend a standard control, inheriting from that control itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the best and proper way to customize and extend a standard
>   XAML control by code AND Xaml, in UWP environment?

Simplely answer: You can use templated Control template.

There is a [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8035) about this, you can start from 30mins from this video.

Generally speaking, there are two kind of ways for us to customize a control:

1. UserControl
2. Templated Control

For UserControl, it is used for light customization and you just need to use it in your own project.
For Templated Control, it's a basic way for us to customize our controls.
For your scenario, actually it won't have too many differences here, You can just inherit the control you want and then customize it with your code from code level and also Xaml level.

Comment: In the video they say they create a copy of the ListView XAML template, but where are these templates located?

Comment: @binaryfunt a quick way: right click your ListView control on your VS UI then create a copy of it. Or you can search on MSDN directly. There are specific pages for those templates.

Comment: Link is no longer active. However, there is a [web archive snapshot of it](http://web.archive.org/web/20211110040651/https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8035)

Answer (score 6):

Are you want something look like this---

**XAML**

If you have single button---

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xECAD;" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/> <!-- alternately use your icon image -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Click me!"/>
    </Grid>            
</Button>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

If you have multiple button use that template--

Steps-

1) Create a class "ButtonWithIcon.cs" or xyz.cs.

```
public class AdvancedButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconContentProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(string), typeof(AdvancedButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(FontIcon)));

    public string Icon
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IconContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

2) Then in you Page.xaml (for only one page) or app.xaml (for use in whole app) add that template

```
<Style x:Key="AdvancedButtonTemplate" TargetType="local:AdvancedButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:AdvancedButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                            
                        <TextBlock x:Name="FontIcon" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Width="40" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Grid.Row="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

3) Then Use That custom button in your  page where you want

```
<local:AdvancedButton Height="55" Width="250" Style="{StaticResource AdvancedButtonTemplate}" Content="New" Icon="&#xECAD;" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" />
```

4) Build Solution else it will show blue error underline.

**Output**

**Note: here i customize template according to my normal understanding you need to customize some font size and style in template according to your need and also add margin if you need in textblocks in template- look into last 3 element "textblocks","content presenter".**

[image: Output]

Comment: I already knew about this, but in this way I would have to repeat it every time I need it.  I don’t want inline solutions... I would like to have a customized control that I could port in every app and include even in a Nuget package.

Comment: Okay you want to customise whole template, it is good idea only when you want to apply customised template in multiple button if you have single button , you can use above method, or wait i will try to update answer